# Iteration in dict and string with function of 2 variables

Tags: python, winsound

In order to play a note, we need to know its frequency and how long it should play. To do this, in exercise I have the following two variables:

A dictionary called freqs where the keys are strings representing a character name and the values ​​are numbers representing frequencies.

```
freqs = {"la": 220,
         "si": 247,
         "do": 261,
         "re": 293,
         "mi": 329,
         "fa": 349,
         "sun": 392,
         }
```

And strings that include the song notes:

```
notes =
"sol,250-mi,250-mi,500-fa,250-re,250-re,500-do,250-re,250-mi,250-fa,250-sol,250-sol,250-sol,500"
```

The strings are constructed as follows:

A comma appears after each character, followed by a number representing the length of time the character should play. Each character is separated from one another by a dash.
in the first stage
I used the split method to split the character strings by the hyphen. And I checked that it was iterable

In order to play a character, I'm supposed to use a skeleton
 Next code:

```
import winsound
...
winsound.Beep (frequency, duration)
```

When the Beep function receives two parameters: the frequency of a character and the length of time to be played. (duration, frequency)

I need to write a program that plays the song "Little Jonathan" according to the string of notes in the notes (which signifies the structure of the song) to create iterable from the above character strings and run it for loop, or use the next function.

That's  my code so far, didn't  work well. How do I proceed from here?

```
def Beep(frequency, duration ):

    for word in duration:
          yield frequency[word]

frequency={"la": 220,"si": 247,"do": 261,"re": 293,"mi": 329,"fa": 
           349,"sol": 392,
          }

res = Beep(['sol,250', 'mi,250', 'mi,500', 'fa,250', 're,250', 're,500', 'do,250', 're,250', 'mi,250', 'fa,250', 'sol,250', 'sol,250', 'sol,500'],frequency)


print(next(res))
```

the desired output  :

```
250,392  
500,329  
250,349  
250,293  
500,293  
250,261  
250,293  
250,329  
250,349  
250,392 
250,392 
500,392
```

Comment: Your `Beep` function expects `frequency, duration` but you seem to be passing it `song_string, frequency_lookup_table`?

Comment: song_string  ?
i  don't  have  that  value....

Comment: What is `solar` in the notes?

Comment: what is `solar` ?

Comment: As in a string containing the song, I see you called it `notes`. Also, I see you have manually broken it into a list. I think that `Beep` should accept something more like a single note so like this `Beep(293, 500)`. Your task is to convert the string `notes` to ` list to pass iteratively into `Beep`.

Comment: Looks like you are calling the function `Beep` with the arguments in inverted order. You have defined it `Beep(dict, list)` but you call it as `Beep(list, dict)`

Comment: I fixed it, I had spelling errors, that's the  SOL character

Comment: It seems to me that I did not properly explain my problem with the exercise, I need to run an iterator to run on notes that the song's character name and take from the dict the same values of the characters so that I also have the frequency

Comment: It is not clear if you are using your own Beep function or the one from the library. Why do you define yours?

Answer (score 2):

`Beep` expects a single frequency and duration of that frequency.

You need to beep for every note in the notestring. Thus you need to iterate trough the notes in a way you can use the frequency and duration of said note. Asuming you have filled 1 array with notes and 1 array with durations you can do this

```py
for note, duration in zip(notes, durations):
    winsound.Beep(freqs[note], duration)
```

If you have not yet split the string you can iterate over the split result of the string.

```py
for note in notes.split('-'):
   winsound.Beep(freqs(note.split(',')[1], note.split(',')[0])
```

Comment: I think you have swapped `-` and `,` in your splitting. The notes are `-` separated, each note is a comma separated pair of frequency,duration.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for pointing out the mistake. The notes string was a bit confusing in the original post. I have edited the answer, Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get your tables correctly.

```
notes = "sol,250-mi,250-mi,500-fa,250-re,250-re,500-do,250-re,250-mi,250-fa,250-sol,250-sol,250-sol,500"

song = []
for block in notes.split('-'):
    note, duration = block.split(',')
    song.append((note, int(duration)))
```

Then the function. I assume you are using `winsound.Beep()` and you want a function that call Beep for each note:duration pair in your `song`. If so, the following function will do the job.

```
def play(song):
    freq_table = {
        "la": 220,
        "si": 247,
        "do": 261,
        "re": 293,
        "mi": 329,
        "fa": 349,
        "sol": 392,
    }
    for note, duration in song:
        frequency = freq_table[note]
        print(frequency, duration)
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

play(song)
```

Comment: why is `song` a dictionary? It's should surely be a list of tuples, otherwise you lose the order as well as any repeated notes.

Comment: and  the  : notes =
"sol,250-mi,250-mi,500-fa,250-re,250-re,500-do,250-re,250-mi,250-fa,250-sol,250-sol,250-sol,500"   ?

Comment: @Dan You are super right! I'll fix it immediately. I have rushed into it.

Comment: First of all thanks to the answer, but something is not clear to me in the code you sent, where is the value notes?

Comment: @אמיליעמית Yep. I have fixed it.

Comment: I still can't figure out what I'm calling a function?

Comment: @אמיליעמית Are you sure you want to `yield`?

Comment: Not necessarily,ן i need  to iterate  somehow with for loop or  yield.Do iteration no matter how

Comment: Your last line `play(song)` should probably be `play(notes)` - otherwise this look like the answer to me

Comment: @Dan I have put the parsing of `notes` into `song` outside the function. Of course, it could be moved inside the function body; in that case, you would pass 'notes' as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of strange stuff in your `notes` variable, so i will assume its a typo, and it is indeed in the format of `note-duration` separated by coma and space.

In that case this should work:

```
for i in notes.split(", "):
    winsound.Beep(freqs[i.split("-")[1]], i.split("-")[0])
```

Comment: What are the strange things? Tell me and I'll explain

Comment: the  value "notes"  is  the  "words" of the  song '  the Characters  of the  song

Comment: @אמיליעמית There is no patter in the string. It start with a simple `sol` and afterwards there is a pattern of `note-duration` and at the very end there is a simple `500` again.

Comment: So how can I play the song with these values: frequency and duration

Comment: @אמיליעמית As I described in my answer. The problem is that your notes variable is NOT in the format of frequency-duartion

Comment: 250,392  (sol)
250,329  (mi)
500,329  (mi)
250,349  (fa)
250,293  (re)
500,293  (re)
250,261  (do)
250,293  (re)
250,329  (mi)
250,349  (fa)
250,392 (sol)
250,392 (sol)
500,392 (sol)


These are the values that the iterator should print, one value takes from freqs that is the frequency of the character
And the second value is from notes which is the length of the sound

Comment: @אמיליעמית Then please add the desired output to the question. It looks like you want to call `Beep()`, not `print()`. Also, thee are two `Beep()` one from `winsound` and one define by you `def Beep(...)`. Why? Your question is unclear, please remake it or it will be closed.

Comment: I added the desired output

Comment: the desired output:

250,392  
500,329  
250,349  
250,293  
500,293  
250,261  
250,293  
250,329  
250,349  
250,392 
250,392 
500,392

Comment: the desired output